# Python3 check a list of dicts against another

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to check two lists of dicts against each other. The goal is to confirm that the `country` in list1 also exist in list2. If it does not it should print that the `country` does not exist if it exist it will print out that the country exists.

Both lists start with country however the length differs with different keys and values as shown below.

```
list1 = [{ 'country': 'brazl', 'state': 'oregon'}, { 'country': 'japan', 'state': 'chicago'}, { 'country': 'australia', 'state': 'washington', 'water': 'clean'} { 'country':'china']
list2 = ...
```

Comment: So the JSON part of the problem is already solved and you're working with two lists. Okay. I'm editing out the JSON aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
countries1 = list(item['country'] for item in list1)
countries2 = list(item['country'] for item in list2)
compare1 = [country for country in countries1 if country not in countries2] # doesnt exist
compare2 = [country for country in countries1 if country in countries2] # exist
```

case state:

```
state1 = list(item['state'] for item in list1)
state2 = list(item['state'] for item in list2)
compare1 = [state for state in state1 if state not in state2] # doesnt exist
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
list1 = [{ 'country': 'brazil', 'state': 'oregon' , 'some_key': 'some _value'}, { 'country': 'japan', 'state': 'chicago'}, { 'country': 'australia', 'state': 'washington', 'water': 'clean'}, { 'country':'china', 'state':'Tokio'}]

list2 = [{ 'country': 'brazil', 'state': 'oregon'}, { 'country': 'america', 'state': 'new york'}, { 'country': 'australia', 'state': 'washington', 'water': 'clean'},{ 'country':'china'}]


def check_key(dict_key):
    # Check if key exist in all dictionaries
    for item in list1+list2:
        if dict_key in item.keys():
            status = True
        else:
            status = False
            return status

    return status


# If key exist in all dictionaries compare
# If key doesnt exist in all dictionaries skip to next key
for k in list1[0].keys():
    # Ckeck if key exist in all dictionaries
    status = check_key(k)
    # test
    #print ("key: {}, exist in all".format(k)) if status else print ("key: {}, doesn't exist in all".format(k)) # key: country, exist in all
    if status: # True
        # If key exist in all dictionaries
        values1 = list(item[k] for item in list1)
        values2 = list(item[k] for item in list2)
        compare1 = [country for country in values1 if country not in values2]  # doesnt exist
        print ("For key: {}, values which doesnt exist in list2: {}".format(k,compare1))
        compare2 = [country for country in countries1 if country in countries2]  # exist
        print("For key: {}, values which exist in list2: {}".format(k, compare2))
    else: # False
        # If key doesnt exist in all dictionaries
        pass
```

Output:

```
For key: country, values which doesnt exist in list2: ['japan']
For key: country, values which exist in list2: ['brazil', 'australia', 'china']
```

UPDATED CODE no.2 :) :

```
list1 = [{ 'country': 'brazl', 'state': 'oregon'}, { 'country': 'japan', 'state': 'chicago'}, { 'country': 'australia', 'state': 'washington', 'water': 'clean'},{'country':'china'}]

for item in list1:
    if 'state' in item.keys():
        print (item['state'])
```

output:

```
oregon
chicago
washington
```

Comment: How can you define if you want to compare the second value. Like in this case state?

Comment: Thanks. However in my case state does not exist is all of the lists so I got the error: `Keyerror: 'state'`. Is it possible to check if state exists, and if it does not it should should skip to next.

Comment: I just updated my code ,I hope that it will help :)

Comment: Thanks! I think you misunderstood or I didn't explain good enough. I wanted to print out the states in list1 only. I was not able to do that because states did not exist in some entries within list1. Can this be done?

Comment: little missunderstanding :) when you say states you mean at values : oregon,chicago,washington?

Comment: Yes, thats true.

Comment: I update my post with UPDATED CODE no.2(code which will print all states from list1 ) :)  @user3580316

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190913/discussion-between-user3580316-and-ncica).

Answer (score 2):

you can for example make a set of all the countries from list1 and another set from the countries from list2:

```
countries1 = set(item.get("country", "unknown") for item in list1)
countries2 = set(item.get("country", "unknown") for item in list2)
```

then make a difference of the two:

```
print("countries in list1 but not in list2:")
print(countries1 - countries2)
```

or an union:

```
print("countries in list1 and in list2:")
print(countries1 & countries2)
```

Comment: How can I have a if - else statement. Like if the country exist in both files it should do something and if it does not it should print `country does not exist in file2`

Comment: is it possible to check for state?

Answer (score 1):

Make sets of the countries present in each list and subtract them, leaving you with a set of countries in list1, but not in list2, like this:

```
missing_countries = set([i['country'] for i in list1]) - set([i['country'] for i in list2])
print("Countries not in list2:")
for i in missing_countries:
    print(i)
```